# Read lines of a file with parallel stream and extract index

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to read the content of a file with a parallel stream and I need to know the number of each line, is it possible?
I've seen other posts related with calculating the index iterating over a stream, but they don't use parallel streams.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(myFile, myCharset).parallel()) {
    stream.forEach(line -> { 
        // calculate index 
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want only to read the lines in parallel and just to display them or to process them in a parallel stream? Because if you want to process them in parallel using forEach, then there is a way of doing but implies some concurrency code.

Comment: That concurrency code pretty much conteracts the benefits of a parallel stream, doesn't it?

Comment: What are you going to do with that line number?

Comment: The program I'm writing analizes the content of a huge file (2GB), and records in the database the number of the line that contains an error and the results of the validation. In parallel it takes around 20 minutes, otherwise it takes up to 1 hour.

Comment: Then, assuming that there is a significantly smaller number of errors than lines, you could write a custom `Collector` for the operation. The crucial point is that the actual line number won't be available during the concurrent processing but will be at the end when assembling the final list of errors. Afterwards, they can get transferred to the database. If that's not feasible, you could transfer the errors during the processing when the database allows to fix the line numbers in a subsequent update.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. A parallel stream means that all stream elements are processed in parallel. To get an index, you would need a sequential stream.

Apart from that, that method has an unknown numer of lines, so processing them in parallel is most likely not gaining any performance anyways, apart from the index problem.